# How to get ParseUI demo to work on a new project?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parseui

I want to build the ParseUI demo project found here https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/tree/master/ParseUIDemo.

There isn't any documentation on this page. How do I get the ParseUI demo into a new project?

Would the steps be:
Add the Parse sdk to the project
Update the parse credentials in the project
Add parse ui to the project (I would use cocoa pods)
Copy and paste the parse ui demo files to the project

Answer (score 0):

Download the zip (link on the right-hand side) from here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS

Then just unzip and run the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: Thanks. When I build and run the project it compiles ok but the simulator doesn't load. I don't see any storyboards or xibs?